# Android ListView itemClick

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make a `ListView` elements clickable but I'm getting `ClassCastException`. Here is the code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            exit();

        }
    });

    TextView title_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Menu_Title_1);
    title_1.setText(decodeString(R.string.menu_title1));
    title_1.setTypeface(getTitleTypeface());

    TextView title_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Menu_Title_2);
    title_2.setText(decodeString(R.string.menu_title2));
    title_2.setTypeface(getTitleTypeface());

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_Menu);

    String[] items = {  decodeString(R.string.menu_igraj),
                        decodeString(R.string.menu_rezultati),
                        decodeString(R.string.menu_postavke),
                        decodeString(R.string.menu_pomoc),
                        decodeString(R.string.menu_izlaz) };

     CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(items);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);

     list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int 
                                                    position, long id) {

                TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;                 
                String strText = textView.getText().toString();

                if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_igraj)))    
                    {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, GameActivity.class));
                } else if 
                    (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_pomoc))) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, HelpActivity.class));
                } else if 
                   (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_postavke))) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                } else if 
                  (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_rezultati))) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ScoresActivity.class));
                } else if 
                    (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_izlaz))) {
                    exit();
                }

            }
        });

}

private void exit() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    //startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    finish();
}

private Typeface getTitleTypeface() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), 
            decodeString(R.string.tf_angelic));
    return tf;
}

private Typeface getListTypeface() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),  
            decodeString(R.string.tf_jennifer));
    return tf;
}

private String decodeString(int id) {
    String string = getResources().getString(id);
    return string;
}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] m_items;
    LayoutInflater m_inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(String items[]) {

        m_items = items;
        m_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MenuActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return m_items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);             
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_List_Item);
            holder.tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_overlay));
            holder.tv.setTypeface(getListTypeface());
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();              
        }
        holder.tv.setText(m_items[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
}
```

}

I also tryed with `ArrayAdapter` but it wont work, i always get a runtimeException. When i debug it, it shows this line:   `TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked`;    is getting an error.

**The logcat:**

```
10-23 12:59:33.356: E/ActivityThread(638):  at      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-23 12:59:33.356: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638): null
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d50490 that was originally bound here
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-23 12:59:33.387: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-23 12:59:33.387: W/ActivityManager(278): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fe0b80
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d31c70 that was originally bound here
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d31c70 that was originally bound here
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-23 12:59:33.406: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638): null
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d31c70 that was originally bound here
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-23 12:59:33.506: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_List_Item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="test"
    android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_dim" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show R.layout.list_item. And don't paste all file. -1

Comment: Only i needed to do was to make the xml of TextView type, not as RelativeLayout. It works now...

Comment: @palve it is better to get item from adapter then from a view. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, you can not directly get `TextView` from `itemClicked`

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int 
                                                    position, long id) {

                TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.textView_List_Item);;                 
                String strText = textView.getText().toString();

                if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_igraj)))    
                    {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, GameActivity.class));
                } else if 
                    (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_pomoc))) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, HelpActivity.class));
                } else if 
                   (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_postavke))) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                } else if 
                  (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_rezultati))) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ScoresActivity.class));
                } else if 
                    (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_izlaz))) {
                    exit();
                }

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Yes, i already tried this, but when i use this code it always shows the same activity...no matter which item i click

Comment: @pavle Did you check what text you getting at line `String strText = textView.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your clicked item is not of a TextView class; your cast is wrong in that line, you need to get the TextView from the item's view that has been clicked, that view is being passed to you through the click callback.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the position from the `ListView` that was selected and retrieve the `String` from your `ListViewAdapter` data.

For example:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                        View itemClicked,
                        int position, 
                        long id) {

            String selectedItem = items[position];//you may need to make String[] items final for this, or make it a global variable to the class

            //do stuff with String
}
```

This way, you don't have to worry about shakey class castings. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1) Change your customAdapter class's getItem method

```
// CustomAdapter 
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // return arg0;
    return m_items[arg0];
}
```

2) Change your onItemClicked logic;

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {
          CustomAdapter customAdapter = (CustomAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
          String selectedText = (String)customAdapter.getItem(position);
          // Use your selected text here
     }
}
```

This will solve your problem.